# The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, is a potentially non-nullable type

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

So basically I want to check the status of my app if the user is logged in it redirects the user to the homepage, if the admin logged in it redirects to the dashboard. I have put a return statement there but it said that there might be a null returned. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context,snapshot){
          if(snapshot.hasData){
            final User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
            final userID = user.uid;

            FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('user')
            .doc(userID)
            .get()
            .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
              Map<String, dynamic> data = ds.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
              if(data['role']=='admin') {
                return AdminPage();
              }else {
                return HomePage();
              }
            });
          } else {
            return AuthPage();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

You must return something when the query fails to execute or loads the data.

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context,snapshot){
          if(snapshot.hasData){
            final User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
            final userID = user.uid;

            FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('user')
            .doc(userID)
            .get()
            .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
              Map<String, dynamic> data = ds.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
              if(data['role']=='admin') {
                return AdminPage();
              }else {
                return HomePage();
              }
            });
          return LoadingPage();
          } else {
            return AuthPage();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If I do that it will just shows the loading page though, it does not redirect to the admin or  user page

Comment: try using a futurebuilder inside the stream builder.